# Transition anchor text on hover of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make the text in my anchor tags transition when the mouse hovers over a logo.  I have a transition on the logo that I want to match for the anchor text but the text never transitions. The anchor text visibility is initially set to hidden and should slowly appear. Can this be done with css alone or will I need to use JavaScript or jquery?

Thanks!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mLbdzgg/)

```
<div class="row container">
  <div id="visible">

  <div class="small-4 small-centered medium-3 medium-centered large-2 large-centered columns">
    <div class="circle-logo">
      <a href="#">dp</a>
    </div>
  </div>


<div id="hidden" class="small-8 small-centered medium-9 medium-centered large-10 large-centered columns">
    <ul class="button-group even-4 sans">
      <li><a href="blog.html" class="small button secondary">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
.container a {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.circle-logo {
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
border: 0.8em double;
border-radius: 6em;
z-index: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle-logo a {
font-size: 7em;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
line-height: 0.98;
font-family: Baumans, cursive;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle-logo:hover {
z-index: 1000;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #403E3E;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle-logo:hover a {
color: #FFFFFF;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.button.secondary {
background-color: #868686;
}
.button-group.even-4 li a {
border-left: none;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#visible {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#visible:hover {
  #hidden {
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess logo was the wrong word to describe it. I am referring to the anchor tag inside the circle-logo class.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to do. I am still lost with what you're asking.

Comment: @cport1 I finally got it to work. I just needed to change some html and do a little nesting with sass. I have updated the code and fiddle link so you can see what I was trying to achieve.